# How to insert external pdf file in beamer

Tags: beamer, external-files

Question:

I am making a presentation with beamer in which I want to give link of external pdf file. Because I am using most of the content of that .pdf file in my beamer. Rather than typing all details, can I put a link in beamer so by cliking on it I can easily open it.

Please help me.

Comment: As in any other LaTeX document, with the `hyperref` package and  `\href{URL}{DESCRIPTION}` or `\url{URL}`.

Comment: @Fran Will it work for beamer?

Comment: is the file stored locally beside the presentation, or reachable by an url?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Reachable by an URL One request please guide me. Further if file is stored locally saved.